# comparing two dataframes pandas and getting differences and complete

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

```
df1:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-24 strawberry 15.2 black

df2:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange

result
df1:
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
**2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red**
**2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange**
2013-11-24 strawberry 15.2 black
```

What I want to do is compare these two images and find which lines are in df2 that are not in df1. I want to compare the date (index) and then put the difference in df1 in the same order

Answer (score 1):

You can join both data sets and then drop duplicates:

```
df2.append(df1).drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
         Date       Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-24      Banana  22.1  Yellow
1  2013-11-24      Orange   8.6  Orange
2  2013-11-24       Apple   7.6   Green
3  2013-11-24      Celery  10.2   Green
4  2013-11-25       Apple  22.1     Red
5  2013-11-25      Orange   8.6  Orange
4  2013-11-24  strawberry  15.2   black
```

Comment: @jezrael Ok. In the same order now.